# Can you use multiprocessing or threading on a list of coroutines to speed up program execution?

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, coroutine

I currently have a list of 2000 coroutines I have created. I want to use multiprocessing or threading (the bottleneck is I/O, so I assume threading would be preferable) to speed my code up by having each process/thread be responsible for evaluating a chunk of the coroutines (maybe 500 each). Is this possible?

I've looked into asyncio.semaphore as possible solutions to my problem, but it doesn't quite do what I want (in fact, when trying asyncio.semaphore, I got a "too many files open" bug). I'm running Python3.6

```
async def some_coroutine_here(x):
    print('start: ', x)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('done ', x)
    return x

async def main():
    x = await asyncio.gather(*[some_coroutine_here(x) for x in range(2000)]) # list of coroutines

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

For the above code, which only uses one process and one thread, could I maybe use multiprocessing or threading on top of async to speed up execution? The coroutines are all independent of each other and do not need to communicate or share any information.

A connected question, I suppose, would be: would this actually result in a speedup?

Comment: If the bottleneck is I/O, the best way is to use a library that can take care of non-blocking I/O for you. For HTTP for instance, you can use aiohttp (https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: It's not HTTP, but I have been using something similar to that. However, can you use multithreading or multiprocessing on *top* of a library like that?

Comment: You could, but IIRC asyncio eventloops are single threaded, so maybe you can have multiple eventloops. I don't expect that to provide much improvement though - if you're I/O bound, more threads really aren't needed. For instance, redis manages to be highly performant and blazingly fast while being single threaded.

Comment: I see. Would you be able to use multiple processes instead in this case? Or would multiprocessing not speed it up either?

Comment: Yep. Only case when multi processing/threading will help is if you're doing some compute as well (eg crunch some numbers and then sent that over the network).

Comment: Okay, thank you. If I were to do that, though, how would I go about implementing multiprocessing here to achieve the task described in the question? It might not be useful for this case, but I'd still like to know for another possible use case.

Comment: generally, you can't speed up IO even more than asyncio already does. Multithreading/multiprocessing may help to speed up cpu bound parts (but be aware of the GIL) or disk IO. Asyncio, multithreading, multiprocessing are all the tools for asynchronous programming, and in general simply combining them won't gain much benefit

Comment: I understand, thanks! But if we were to combine them in this instance, how would we do it?